# Is there any way to install Julia-lang version 0.4.2 on OSX?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn julia language and I want to install specifically 0.4.2 version of it. When I look at the julia's [website](http://julialang.org/downloads/), I see that 0.4.3's dmg file is in website, however I was not able to find and download the dmg of 0.4.2 version of julia. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get it here:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/julialang/bin/osx/x64/0.4/julia-0.4.2-osx10.7+.dmg

Any reason you wanted 0.4.2 rather than the more current 0.4.3?

Comment: Thank you so much, actually yes there is a reason. The package that I need to use has been tested on that version. In 0.4.3 I got an error and I try to understand whether it is due to julia version or not.

Comment: Makes sense. If it is due to the version of Julia, please file an issue – patch updates should ideally not break anything.